# Circular Point Counter Java or Circle Progress Bar

Tags: java, progress-bar, draw, geometry, points

For my project, I am trying to create a circular progress bar to show how many points the user has. I currently have the following code to create the circle.

```
public void Paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.translate(80, 80);
    g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(270));
    Arc2D arc = new Arc2D.Float(Arc2D.PIE);
    arc.setFrameFromCenter(new Point(0, 0), new Point(80, 80));
    arc.setAngleStart(1);
    arc.setAngleExtent(-totalPoints*3.6);
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.draw(arc);
    g2.fill(arc);
}
```

I am also trying to create it from another file. Should I create a JPanel or can I add it to a label? Also if I use a panel how can I add it using code?

I am using gridbag to set locations and I am not using the drag and drop function to create the JFrame and JPanels that Netbeans has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're creating a custom component, something like this:

```
public class CircleProgress extends JComponent {
```

In which case to use this in another Swing class, you'd treat it as any other `Component`, for example:

```
CircleProgress progress = new CircleProgress();
...

Panel p = new Panel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(progress, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It would be strange to add it to a `Label`, rather than a `Panel`.

Comment: When I am using the add it says it can't find the Symbol. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's been a while since I used Swing.

Comment: is there a way to set a max for the counter? so It can show current user points and compare to max current points.

Comment: Of course, your component is just another Java Class, you're in control of the attributes (e.g. add a `setMax(int max)` method) and it can of course maintain state.  I would recommend asking a new question if you get stuck, you're more likely to get a detailed response.